# Running ASP.NET MVC application with SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am beginner in ASP.NET MVC. I followed one tutorial to build a simple web application. First, I created a database in SQL Server Management Studio, and I integrated it in my ASP.NET MVC app. It runs fine on my machine, but when I try to run it on another laptop it does not recognize my database.

Here's the error:

```
return View(db.Restoran.ToList());   // on this line
```

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: 'The underlying provider failed on Open.'

Comment: Does this other computer have the database?  Did you update your connection string when copying the application?

Comment: Which database server is the application connection string pointing at? Perhaps it's easiest to post the connection string (with login details hidden)

Comment: If the database is up and running (whether it's a local DB or external one), make sure the connection string is set properly.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you must install SQL Server Management System in the laptop too, and create a database with the same name and login details...i hope it help.

this way it would be better as you won't have to do any changes in the code